# materializecss sidenav not working in angular

Tags: angular

Actually am trying to implement materializecss in my angular project but its not working for me 
here what i have done

```
npm install --save materialize-css jquery font-awesome
```

Angular.json

```js
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
             "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css",
             "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
            ]
```

am trying to implement navbar responsive

```html
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
  </ul>
```

And Also am getting input like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have added the styles and JavaScript paths at the wrong location.

You might have added them to:

> projects > demo > architect > test > options > `styles` and `scripts`

The **correct path** to add them would be:

> projects > demo > architect > build > options > `styles` and `scripts`

On second thought, it is better to add the styles to the `styles.css` file instead to keep them at a centralized spot. Like this:

```
@import "~materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css";
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
```

> Here's a [**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-materialize-css-example?file=angular.json) for your ref.

Comment: but still navbar not working tap on menu responsiveness not working here 
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-materialize-css-example?file=angular.json

Answer (score 0):

First write this import statement

```
import M from 'materialize-css';
```

Secondly write this in your `ngAfterViewInit()`:

```
   ngAfterViewInit() {
     var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
     var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems, {preventScrolling:true});
   }
```

**Working demo :**  [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-materialize-carousel-ev8ti8)